# Getting error in Curl - Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with known CA certificates

Tags: ssl, curl, openssl

I am getting the below error while making ssl connection with self signed certificate.
"Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with known CA certificates"

It is working fine with CA signed certificate.
I am setting the below  using `curl_easy_setopt()`.

```
curl_easy_setopt(MyContext, CURLOPT_CAPATH, CA_CERTIFICATE_PATH)
curl_easy_setopt(MyContext, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,TRUE);
```

The curl version:

```
libcurl-7.19.7-26
```

Openssl version is:

```
0_9_8u
```

Please let me know how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 8):

By default CURL will generally verify the SSL certificate to see if its valid and issued by an accepted CA. To do this, curl uses a bundled set of CA certificates.

If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use the -k (or --insecure) option. Here's an example:

```
curl --noproxy -k \* -D - https://127.0.0.1:443/some-secure-endpoint
```

Answer (score 8):

> **Security issue**: This answer disables a security feature. Do not use this in production!

For php it is possible to switch off curl's verification of the certificate (see warning below)  e.g. for curl_exec

```
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

(evaluate the security risk yourself, in my case it was on a partner company's server and the file required contained no secure information - just happened to be on a secure server)

Comment: Bad practice, don't disable SSL verification!

Answer (score 6):

We fixed a similar issue on CentOS 6 by updating curl to the latest version available in the standard repositories and installing the newest ca-certificates bundle:

```
yum update curl
yum install ca-certificates
```

Comment: Did it work for the self signed  certificates? I have also tried curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); , but still the error persists for me.

Comment: @VamsiKrishnaNeelam Not sure I'm afraid.. this was nearly 4 years ago, good luck though

Answer (score 4):

libcurl performs peer SSL certificate verification by default.  This is done
by using CA cert bundle that the SSL library can use to make sure the peer's
server certificate is valid.

If you communicate with HTTPS or FTPS servers using certificates that are
signed by CAs present in the bundle, you can be sure that the remote server
really is the one it claims to be.

Until 7.18.0, curl bundled a severely outdated ca bundle file that was
installed by default. These days, the curl archives include no ca certs at
all. You need to get them elsewhere. See below for example.

For more to know about Peer SSL Certificate Verification visit http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

Answer (score 2):

Though this error happened in the case of using `git clone` rather than with using `curl`, I've recently stumbled across an identical error message:

> Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with known CA certificates

Similar to [Arth's findings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40265963/1167750), something that worked for CentOS 6 *(in order to successfully use HTTPS URLs with `git clone` for related GitLab repositories)* involved updating the trusted certificates on the server *(i.e., the server that is using HTTPS)*, using [the following steps](https://briansnelson.com/How_to_add_trusted_root_certificates):

1. `sudo yum install ca-certificates`
2. `sudo update-ca-trust enable`
3. `sudo cp /path/to/your_new_cert.crt /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/`
4. `sudo update-ca-trust extract`

Perhaps the same certificate steps can be applied for the case of `curl` *(or other similar scenarios)* for users on CentOS in the future.

Answer (score 2):

As we checked and observed/ Found in Centos 8 .
Due to Proxy issue your packages not allowing you to get accessible to update or download any packages.
try to add `sslverify=0` in file `/etc/dnf/dnf.conf`

**Its worked for me**.

*Also make sure you must have proper internet acess on your server.*

Comment: Its worked for mee too. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> **Security issue**: This answer disables a security feature. Do not use this in production!

In 'C'

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

worked for me